# Automator Quick Action / Workflow has no permission to open files

Tags: automator, filesystem, python, screen-capture

I'm creating a Quick Action in Automator to replace the default screenshot functionality on Mac as following:

1. Take screenshot
2. Pass screenshot path to Python shell script
3. Have that script upload it to my web server

[image: My Automator workflow]

Now, when I am in Safari (or any other application, but Safari for explanation purposes) and hit the keyboard shortcut that I've assigned to this Quick Action, I receive the following error:

```
The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/name/Downloads/Screenshots.png'”
```

The third line in my script is a simple call to the above path using Python's `open()` function.
In the case of this example, the error would go away if I grant Full Disk Access to Safari. That's great, but I obviously mean to take screenshots of other apps as well, and manually granting each application access to this folder is an obvious no-go. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Welcome to Apple's security restrictions. You have to grant Full Disk Access to each app. (You're lucky that they can hand off to a script at all, and I wouldn't count on that continuing.)

Comment: Maybe a different approach would work better... Use the **macOS** default _keyboard shortcut_ for **Screenshots** while setting a location for them to a _folder_ created outside of the default _folders_ created by **macOS**. Then use a **Folder Action** to process the _files_ saved to that _folder_. That would get the job done and not have to deal with all the **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** issues going the route currently are.

Comment: @user3439894 That does sound like it might work! I'll give that a try and update accordingly